# Question hidden from index page—bug?

Tags: bug

Not long after I posted [Staying more than ninety days in Andorra, San Marino, Monaco, Vatican, …](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163633/staying-more-than-ninety-days-in-andorra-san-marino-monaco-vatican), I came back to the site to add a comment.  It was not visible in the index.  I clicked on my avatar and it was also not shown in my list of questions.  But my rep menu showed that someone had already voted on it.

**Bug?**

Comment: [shouldiblamecaching.com](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Caching might explain it missing from the index page that I had visited earlier that day.  But not missing from my profile, that I hadn't previously been to in several months.  And it _is_ on the index page fifteen minutes after posting, without clearing cache or history.

Comment: I can see the question in your profile. Is it still not visible to you? Are you sure you're sorting by "Newest"?

Comment: Again, it did appear within fifteen minutes after posting.  But not ten minutes after.  For me—obviously whoever voted on it could see it before that.

Comment: If you're on the homepage already, posts will fill immediately (the bar that says "load n questions with new activity") but if you visit/refresh the homepage, it takes about 5 minutes for a question to appear publicly. Even if you see it due to the new activity load and then refresh the page, it'll disappear. That part, at least is normal and bydesign... not sure about how long it should take to appear on your profile, though.

Comment: The questions page is less cached, about 1 minute instead of 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't in the homepage of the site because the list of questions there is [cached for five minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364181/question-hidden-from-index-page-bug#comment1215360_364181).

It wasn't in your profile page because the default sort is by votes, and you have many questions with more votes, hence it wasn't in there. (The summary in profile shows only top 5, using the selected sort.)

This one you can "fix" yourself by choosing sort by activity or newest:

[image: sorting questions in profile by activity]

Comment: Actually, on the profile I tapped “view more” and it wasn’t there.

Comment: That's weird, but guess it is there now?

Comment: Yeah, it is.  Didn’t check till now, but I assumed that when it appeared in the index, it would also appear in the profile.